# How to find an eigenvector that corresponds to it.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A=$\begin{pmatrix} -7 & -9 \\ 6 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$

(a) Is the vector v = $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{matrix} \right] $
an eigenvector of A? If so, what is the corresponding eigenvalue?

(b) Given that −1 is an eigenvalue of A, find an eigenvector that corresponds to it.

**My work**

I got the eigen values as $-10,11$

But, how to find part b).

I am getting the eigen vector as $\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right] $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A.\binom1{-1}=\binom2{-2}=2\binom1{-1}$, $v$ is an eigenvector and its eigenvalue is $2$. The other eigenvalue is $-1$. A corresponding eigenvector is $\binom3{-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

You have for every eigenvector the relation $Ax = \lambda x$. This is the same as saying $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$ for different couples of $\lambda $ and $x$. So in your case, you simply want to find the vectors $x$ which satisfies the above relation for $ \lambda = -1$. That is, you want to solve $(A+I)x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Do the multiplication
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is the result a scalar multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$?

For the other eigenvalue, find the null space of
$$
A+I=\begin{bmatrix}
-6 & -9 \\
6 & 9
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since the characteristic polynomial is $X^2-\operatorname{trace}(A)X+\det(A)=X^2-X-2$, it's difficult to know how you computed the eigenvalues as $-10$ and $11$.

Answer (score 0):

See below to check where you got off the track and got $-10,11$.

Eigenvalues:
$$\begin{vmatrix} -7-\lambda& -9 \\ 6 & 8-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=0 \Rightarrow \lambda^2-\lambda -2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_1=-1, \lambda_2=2.$$
Eigenvector for $\lambda=-1$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-7+1 & -9\\ 6&8+1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=0\Rightarrow 6x_1+9x_2=0 \Rightarrow x_2=-\frac{2}{3}x_1 \Rightarrow \\
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\-\frac 23\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} -\frac 32\\1\end{pmatrix},\cdots$$

Eigenvector for $\lambda=2$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-7-2 & -9\\ 6&8-2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=0\Rightarrow 6x_1+6x_2=0 \Rightarrow x_2=-x_1 \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you get $x1$ and $x2$ in the first case because what I did was let $x2=1$ and got $x1=-3/2$

Comment: Your answer is also correct. Note that infinitely many eigenvectors exist for the eigenvalue $\lambda=-1$. See my addition above.

Comment: So, the exact value doesn't matter right.

Comment: When choosing one eigenvector from many possible one should try to choose as small as possible integer elements (i.e. avoid big numbers and fractions). Though it is not always possible.

Comment: for additional practice, you can refer to: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/LA_Eigen.aspx